# Adding layers and bidirectionality to custom LSTM cell in pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I use a very custom LSTM-cell inspired by http://mlexplained.com/2019/02/15/building-an-lstm-from-scratch-in-pytorch-lstms-in-depth-part-1/.

I use it to look at intermediate gating values. My question is, how would I expand this class to have an option for adding more layers and for adding bidirectionality? Should it be wrapped in a new class or added in the present one?

```
class Dim(IntEnum):
    batch = 0
    seq = 1

class simpleLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_sz: int, hidden_sz: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_sz
        self.hidden_size = hidden_sz
        # input gate
        self.W_ii = Parameter(torch.Tensor(input_sz, hidden_sz))
        self.W_hi = Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_sz, hidden_sz))
        self.b_i = Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_sz))
        # forget gate
        self.W_if = Parameter(torch.Tensor(input_sz, hidden_sz))
        self.W_hf = Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_sz, hidden_sz))
        self.b_f = Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_sz))
        # ???
        self.W_ig = Parameter(torch.Tensor(input_sz, hidden_sz))
        self.W_hg = Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_sz, hidden_sz))
        self.b_g = Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_sz))
        # output gate
        self.W_io = Parameter(torch.Tensor(input_sz, hidden_sz))
        self.W_ho = Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_sz, hidden_sz))
        self.b_o = Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_sz))

        self.init_weights()

        self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_sz, len(TRG.vocab))


    def init_weights(self):
        for p in self.parameters():
            if p.data.ndimension() >= 2:
                nn.init.xavier_uniform_(p.data)
            else:
                nn.init.zeros_(p.data)

    def forward(self, x, init_states=None ):
        """Assumes x is of shape (batch, sequence, feature)"""
        seq_sz, bs, = x.size()
        hidden_seq = []
        prediction = []

        if init_states is None:
            h_t, c_t = torch.zeros(self.hidden_size).to(x.device), torch.zeros(self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        else:
            h_t, c_t = init_states
        for t in range(seq_sz): # iterate over the time steps
            x_t = x[t, :].float()
            #LOOK HERE!!!
            i_t = torch.sigmoid(x_t @ self.W_ii + h_t @ self.W_hi + self.b_i)
            f_t = torch.sigmoid(x_t @ self.W_if + h_t @ self.W_hf + self.b_f)
            g_t = torch.tanh(x_t @ self.W_ig + h_t @ self.W_hg + self.b_g)
            o_t = torch.sigmoid(x_t @ self.W_io + h_t @ self.W_ho + self.b_o)
            c_t = f_t * c_t + i_t * g_t
            h_t = o_t * torch.tanh(c_t)

            hidden_seq.append(h_t.unsqueeze(Dim.batch))

            pred_t = self.out(h_t.unsqueeze(Dim.batch))
            #pred_t = F.softmax(pred_t)
            prediction.append(pred_t)


        hidden_seq = torch.cat(hidden_seq, dim=Dim.batch)
        prediction = torch.cat(prediction, dim=Dim.batch)
        # reshape from shape (sequence, batch, feature) to (batch, sequence, feature)
        hidden_seq = hidden_seq.transpose(Dim.batch, Dim.seq).contiguous()
        prediction = prediction.transpose(Dim.batch, Dim.seq).contiguous()


        return prediction, hidden_seq, (h_t, c_t)
```

I call it and train using the following as an example.

```
lstm = simpleLSTM(1, 100)
hidden_size = lstm.hidden_size

optimizer = optim.Adam(lstm.parameters())


h_0, c_0 = (torch.zeros(hidden_size, requires_grad=True), 
            torch.zeros(hidden_size, requires_grad=True))

grads = []
h_t, c_t = h_0, c_0


N_EPOCHS = 10

for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    epoch_loss = 0
    for i, batch in enumerate(train):

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        src, src_len = batch.src
        trg = batch.trg
        trg = trg.view(-1)


        predict, output, hidden_states = lstm(src)
        predict = predict.t().unsqueeze(1)
        predict= predict.view(-1, predict.shape[-1])

        loss = criterion(predict,trg)
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        epoch_loss += loss.item()

    print(epoch_loss)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to create another module (say `Bidirectional`) and pass any cell you want to it.

Implementation itself is quite easy to do. Notice that I'm using `concat` operation for joining bi-directional output, you may want to specify other modes like summation etc.

**Please read the comments in the code below, you may have to change it appropriately.**

```
import torch


class Bidirectional(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, cell):
        super().__init__()
        self.cell = cell

    def __call__(self, x, init_states=None):
        prediction, hidden_seq, (h_t, c_t) = self.cell(x, init_states)
        backward_prediction, backward_hidden_seq, (
            backward_h_t,
            backward_c_t,
            # Assuming sequence is first dimension, otherwise change 0 appropriately
            # Reverses sequences so the LSTM cell acts on the reversed sequence
        ) = self.cell(torch.flip(x, (0,)), init_states)
        return (
            # Assuming you transpose so it has (batch, seq, features) dimensionality
            torch.cat((prediction, backward_prediction), 2),
            torch.cat((hidden_seq, backward_hidden_seq), 2),
            # Assuming it has (batch, features) dimensionality
            torch.cat((h_t, backward_ht), 1),
            torch.cat((c_t, backward_ct), 1),
        )
```

When it comes to multiple layers you could do something similiar in principle:

```
import torch


class Multilayer(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *cells):
        super().__init__()
        self.cells = torch.nn.ModuleList(cells)

    def __call__(self, x, init_states=None):
        inputs = x
        for cell in self.cells:
            prediction, hidden_seq, (h_t, c_t) = cell(inputs, init_states)
            inputs = hidden_seq
        return prediction, hidden_seq, (h_t, c_t)
```

Please note you have to pass created cell objects into `Multilayer` e.g.:

```
# For three layers of LSTM, each needs features to be set up correctly
multilayer_LSTM = Multilayer(LSTM(), LSTM(), LSTM())
```

You may also pass classes instead of instances into constructor and create those inside `Multilayer` (so `hidden_size` matches automatically), but those ideas should get you started.